# Blocks in Swift shows error "Missing argument for parameter #2 in call"

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I'm now using Jonas Gessner's [JGActionSheet](https://github.com/roundhouse/JGActionSheet) with Swift in my project, and the sample was written by Objective-C, when I tried to convert the block to Swift, Xcode shows the error "Missing argument for parameter #2 in call", here is the code I written and the screenshot:

## Objective-C Sample

```
JGActionSheet *sheet = [JGActionSheet actionSheetWithSections:sections];
[sheet setButtonPressedBlock:^(JGActionSheet *sheet, NSIndexPath *indexPath) 
{
    [sheet dismissAnimated:YES];
}];
```

## Code I written in Swift

```
let actionSheet = JGActionSheet(sections: sections)
actionSheet.buttonPressedBlock {
    (sheet: JGActionSheet!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
    actionSheet.dismissAnimated(true)
}
```

## Error screenshot

[Missing argument for parameter #2 in call](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nogjjpgs3czw1w/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-22%20at%201.17.59%20AM.png?dl=0)

So please help me to figure this out and thanks very much!

Comment: Try putting an equal sign after `buttonPressedBlock`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`actionSheet.buttonPressedBlock` is a *property*. You are trying to *set* it. So where's your equals sign? This is how you set things in Swift:

```
 myThing.myProperty = myValue
```

The fact that you are trying to set this property to a block (a function) changes nothing. So:

```
let actionSheet = JGActionSheet(sections: sections)
actionSheet.buttonPressedBlock = {
    (sheet: JGActionSheet!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) in
    actionSheet.dismissAnimated(true)
}
```